# Proof that every bounded convex set is a John domain

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

Accordingly to Pommerenke's *Boundary Behaviour of conformal Maps*, a John domain is a bounded simple connected domain in the plane such that there is a $M>0$ that satisfies that for every crosscut $[a,b]$ (i.e. a segment joining two points, $a$ and $b$, in the boundary of $G$) that
$$diam H \leq M |a-b|,$$

where  $diam$ is the usual euclidean diameter and $H$ is the component of $G\setminus[a,b]$ with smallest diameter. If $\partial G$ is smooth, then $G$ looks like a set in the plane not having outward-pointing cusps.

The problem:
I need to show that every bounded convex set is a John domain. But I am very inexperienced with convex sets.

> **My attepmt**
>
> Let $G$ be a bounded convex set. I tried taking the tangent lines at $a$ and $b$, say $T_a$ and $T_b$
> respectively. Assuming they are not parallel (?!), they meet at a
> point $v$, and with those lines and a segment parallel to $[a,b]$ I
> formed the triangle $AvB$ (see draw) such that $G$ is contained in its
> interior.
>
> [image]
>
> I need to show that $diam H/|a-b| \leq k'$ for some constant $k'$; but
> $diam H$ is less or equal than the longest side of the small triangle
> $avb$, lets call the length of this side $l$. Let $L$ be the length of
> the corresponding side of the big triangle $AvB$. Using this and the
> congruence of $avb$ with $AvB$ we have
> $$diam H/|a-b|\leq l/|a-b|=L/|A-B|.$$
>
> If I were able to prove that the longest side of $AvB$ is no longer
> than a constant $K$ depending only on $G$ (our initial bounded convex
> set) and the shortest side is no shorter than a constant k, then I
> could write
>
> $$diam H/|a-b|\leq L/|A-B| \leq K/k$$
>
> with $K/k$ constant, i.e. not depending on the selected points $a$ and
> $b$, and we would be done... But I don't know how to argument the existence of $K$ and $k$ (if they exist) and still have the problem that all this work
> only when $T_a$ is not parallel to $T_b$...

Any suggestion, even using a completely different approach, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by the notation here. $G$ is not defined in the post - is it the convex set we wish to show is a John domain? And what is $H$? I'm not sure what a "component of smallest diameter" is.